# QMainWindow Parameters

Tags: c++, qt

How do you pass the first parameter to a `QMainWindow`?

I want to be able to pass multiple different parameters to a QMainWindow.  My problem is, even after I modify the constructor to allow passing a second/third/fourth parameter, I still cannot find a way to instantiate a `QMainWindow`.  I do not know how to pass the first parameter (the part with `QWidget *parent = 0`).

For example, if I wanted to pass an integer to my `QMainWindow` to instantiate it, would I type: `MainWindow( what_goes_here?, myInt )`?

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {class MainWindow;}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
    explicit MainWindow(int a,QWidget *parent = 0);

MainWindow::MainWindow(int a,QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    qDebug()<<a;
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow w(9);
    w.show();
```

Help you?

Comment: Compiles, so I think it works.  Thanks.  I guess the trick is always make the QWidget pointer the last parameter.

Comment: This is because if you have a default parameter defined, it must be after any required parameters.  This link shows some more info about it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/91563f79(v=vs.80).aspx